# проблема в Js коде на 38 строчке

Tags: javascript

```js
var wolds = [
  "javascript",
  "monkey",
  "amazing",
  "pancake"
];

var word = words[math.floor(math.random() * wolds.length)];

var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
  answerArray[i] + "_";
}

var remainingLetters = word.length;

while (remainingLetters > 0) {
  alert(answerArray.join(""));

  var guess = prompt("Guess a letter,or click Cancel to stop playing.");
  if (guess === null) {

    break;
  } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Please enter a single letter.");
  } else {
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
      if (word[j] === guess) {
        answerArray[j] = guess;
        remainingLetters - -; // вот здесь проблема
      }
    }
  }
}
alert(answerArray.join(" "))
alert("good job! The ansver was" + word);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remainingLetters- -; // вот здесь проблема

лишний пробел между знаками `-`

Comment: спасибо большое